# Scala - multithreading, finish main thread when any child thread finishes

Tags: multithreading, scala

I am building a method that takes x-sized sequence of methods and returns the result of the first method to finish.

```
def invokeAny(work: Seq[() => Int]): Int = ???
```

How can I accomplish this by using Threads? (no futures allowed)

This is the best I have been able to come up with, but seems not to work in all circumstances.

```
def invokeAny(work: Seq[() => Int]): Int = {
    @volatile var result = 0 // set to return value of any work function
    val main = Thread.currentThread()

    val threads: Seq[Thread] = work.map(work => new Thread( new Runnable { 
       def run { result = work(); main.interrupt();  }}))

    threads.foreach(_.start())
    for(thread <- threads) {
      try {
        thread.join()
      }  catch {
        // We've been interrupted: finish
        case e: InterruptedException => return result
    }
    }
    return result
  }
```

Comment: I would suggest to use Futures instead of threads

Comment: Yeah I know, but I would like to know how to do it with Threads

Comment: Use the `java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch` with value of 1. Your child threads would call `latch.countDown()` and main thread would wait for it using `latch.await()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the pretiest answer, but seemed to work:

```
def invokeAny(work: Seq[() => Int]): Int = {
    @volatile var result = 0 // set to return value of any work function
    val main = Thread.currentThread()

    var threads: Seq[Thread] = Seq()

    //Interrupts all threads after one is interrupted
    def interruptAll = {
      main.interrupt()
      for(thread <- threads) {
        thread.interrupt()

      }
    }

    threads = work.map(work => new Thread( 
        new Runnable { 
          def run {
            result = try {
              work() } catch {
                case e:InterruptedException => return
            }
            interruptAll;  

            }
          }))

    threads.foreach(_.start())
    for(thread <- threads) {
      try {
        thread.join()
      } catch {
        // We've been interrupted: finish
        case e: InterruptedException =>  return result
    }
    }
    return result
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a BlockingQueue, no shared mutable state, worker threads write to a queue, the main threads wait till they finish and read from the queue then do something with the results like sum

```
    def invokeAny1(work: Seq[() => Int]): Int = {
    val queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue[Int](work.size)

    val threads: Seq[Thread] = work.map(w => new Thread( new Runnable {
      def run {
        val result= w()
        queue.put(result) }}))

    threads.foreach(_.start())
    threads.foreach(_.join())

    var sum:Int=0

    while(!queue.isEmpty) {
      sum +=queue.take()
    }
      sum
}
```

Using a CountDownLatch.
Worker threads increment an atomic variable.
When all the threads are done the latch is released and the main thread can read the data from the atomic variable

```
def invokeAny2(work: Seq[() => Int]): Int = {

    val total=new AtomicInteger
    val latch= new CountDownLatch(work.size)

    val threads: Seq[Thread] = work.map(w => new Thread( new Runnable {
      def run {

        val result= w()
        total.getAndAdd(result)
        latch.countDown     
      }}))

    threads.foreach(_.start())

    latch.await //wait till the latch is released
    total.get
  }

}
```

Comment: I tested your code, but it seemed to give wrong answers and took four times longer than the code that I posted://

Comment: My code a bit different what you posted, it will wait till all the threads are complete. if you  only want the result of the first thread to finish then make val latch= new CountDownLatch(1) in the 2nd code snippet